# Non-bold italic text

Tags: css, less

I have a bit of text I want to display as non-bolded italic. However, further up in the CSS tree, I have designated that all H2 (this element type) text should be bolded. I know that using

```
font-style: italic;
```

works for italicizing, but it keeps my text bold. How do I tell it to "undo" its bold and then italicize?

I tried

```
font-style: normal;
font-style: italic;
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: it's `font-weight`: http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/font/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
font-weight: normal !important;
```

Comment: yhea! @tereško doesn't like the competition :-)

Comment: My apologies, classic comment collision

Comment: @Dagon , you might be hard pressed to find 3 answers of mine, where that would be a case. And, FYI, comments do not produce any reputation increase.